# split the "Bump Instance" column of the dataframe into multiple rows, such that only one value remains in a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

sample data set :

```
Pin         Ball-out          Bump Instances           Specific Bump Connection   Specific Ball Connection
ATESTCA        Y               W2 E1                      NaN                        NaN
ATESTCA        N               W0 W1 W3 E0 E2 E3          NaN                        NaN
ATESTDQL       Y               W2 E1                      NaN                        NaN
```

code to get till this point:

```
dfPin = pd.read_csv('pinToBall_Bump.csv')
print(dfPin)
dfPin_update1 = dfPin.replace(to_replace='^[io_]+', value='', regex=True)
dfPin_update2 = dfPin_update1.replace(to_replace='^[gddr6_]+', value='', regex=True)
dfPin_update2['Pin'] = dfPin_update2['Pin'].str.upper()
print(dfPin_update2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the space separated fields into list and then use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to transform the dataframe into multiple rows based on the list in the column `Bump Instances`  :

```
dfPin_update2['Bump Instances'] = dfPin_update2['Bump Instances'].str.split(' ')
dfPin_update2 = dfPin_update2.explode('Bump Instances')




print(dfPin_update2)

        Pin Ball-out Bump Instances  Specific Bump Connection  Specific Ball Connection
0   ATESTCA        Y             W2                       NaN                       NaN
0   ATESTCA        Y             E1                       NaN                       NaN
1   ATESTCA        N             W0                       NaN                       NaN
1   ATESTCA        N             W1                       NaN                       NaN
1   ATESTCA        N             W3                       NaN                       NaN
1   ATESTCA        N             E0                       NaN                       NaN
1   ATESTCA        N             E2                       NaN                       NaN
1   ATESTCA        N             E3                       NaN                       NaN
2  ATESTDQL        Y             W2                       NaN                       NaN
2  ATESTDQL        Y             E1                       NaN                       NaN
```